# Rails not rendering assets over SSL (404 Not Found error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ssl, passenger

I am kind of new to Rails and am struggling with an issue that is preventing my assets to be found if I try to access my test app using an SSL connection.

As an example of what I am referring to, if you try to access

http://domain.com/testapp the default rails page loads fine and I have no issues at all.

You can also access a page I created using this route

http://domain.com/testapp/static_pages/home

However the same address, if accessed via HTTPS is returning 404 errors for all of my assets. I am also unable to access any routes (they all return 404).

https://domain.com/testapp

https://domain.com/testapp/static_pages/home

I am currently using an Apache server with Passenger installed, and here is what my virtual host configuration looks like:

```
<Directory /var/www/testapp/public>
    PassengerEnabled on
    PassengerAppRoot /var/www/testapp
    RailsBaseURI /testapp
</Directory>
```

Any ideas of why this might be happening?

Thanks,

Rog

Comment: Are you by chance using Apache named based virtual hosts? If so, take a look at this link to learn about SSL issues with virtual hosts: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts

Comment: Note that this is not an issue with SSL itself. The 404 was transmitted over SSL which proves that the SSL part is working perfectly. It has to do with other parts of your server configuration.

Comment: Thanks @EJP, I suspected as much and have finally managed to fix the problem.

Comment: Cheers Joel, your link didn't answer my question but did put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I finally figured out what was going on so in the interest of others having the same issue, the virtual host configuration was only being applied to the default port (80) so I had to specify port 443 as well.

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
<Directory /var/www/testapp/public>
    PassengerEnabled on
    PassengerAppRoot /var/www/testapp
    RailsBaseURI /testapp
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

For people using Media Temple's DV server, this configurations has to be specified in two separate files (make sure you remove the `VirtualHost` tags).

```
vhost.conf
vhost_ssl.conf
```

And don't forget to restart apache.

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl -K graceful
```